# How do I preserve certain folders when doing a deployment slot swap on an Azure App Service?

Tags: file, azure, storage, azure-storage, azure-web-app-service

I have an Azure app service with two additional slots - one for QA and testing and one for staging.  The deployment process sees me deploying to QA for testing, then to Staging when I'm ready to go live.  Staging is then swapped with the Production application to avoid downtime for users.

The problem I have is that I would like to keep some site content - effectively image files uploaded by users.  They are located in a specific folder - let's say \wwwroot\images.  I can't push these to my TFS system as they are effectively client data files.

Is there a way I can do this deployment without having to back that folder up (using FTP) and restore it after the swap (a 30 minute process)?

In hindsight I could probably have stored the images in the DB - they're not particularly large, but is there another approach that makes more sense?  What about using Azure storage?  What would you do?

Thanks in advance for any advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically for any Storage purpose, it's not recommended way to store images in your code by creating any folder(s). Since Azure web app is a ***PaaS*** model, you don't own the server. Your code is somewhat deployed in any machine(s) among the *Azure DataCenter*.

As you mention, you can use Azure Storage.

[Azure Blob Storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blobs-introduction) is a the which you need to look.

[Here some good demo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-upload-process-images?tabs=net) for uploading images in Azure Blob Storage

Comment: Thanks for confirming and providing an example @Jayendran

Comment: Regarding this, is there a way to preserve certain file, like a `.env` file? I mean, I have one environment file in staging and one different in production. How do I suppose to do in this scenario?